# adding links to PHP array_map

Tags: php

I have managed to return an array with the below code. What's the best solution for returning each element of the '$tag->name' array back as a hyperlink using a foreach

```
<?php
echo implode(', ', array_map(function ($tag) {
    return $tag->name;
}, (array) $post->tags));
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. If you want to return single elements, then what is the connection between the `array_map()` code you posted and what you ask for?

Comment: sorry I guess maybe im looking at a generic method for returning elements of an array in href tags

Comment: Stop using `array_map()` if that is _not_ what you want. Use a simple `for` or `foreach` loop instead to iterate over the array and output whatever you want to make of the single entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `sprintf()` function that put the values on formated string.

```
$post = array(array('tag' => 'stack'), array('tag' => 'overflow'), array('tag' => 'abc'));
echo implode('<br>', array_map(function ($tag) {    return sprintf('<a href=%s>%s</a>', $tag['tag'], $tag['tag']);}, $post));
```

Output:

```
<a href="stack">stack</a><br>
<a href="overflow">overflow</a><br>
<a href="abc">abc</a>
```